# Efficient way to parse large journalctl file to match keywords using Python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

When parsing the journelctl file, keywords to look for are : error, boot, warning, traceback

Once I encounter the keyword, I need to **increment the counter** for each of the keyword and **print the matching line** as well.

So, I have tried as below; reading it from a file and using Collections module - Counter object to keep track of the count along with re.findall :

```
import re
from collections import Counter

keywords = [" error ", " boot ", " warning ", " traceback "]

def journal_parser():
    for keyword in keywords:
        print(keyword)  # just for debugging
        word = re.findall(keyword, open("/tmp/journal_slice.log").read().lower())
        count = dict(Counter(word))
        print(count)
```

Above solution resolves my problem however I am looking forward for much efficient way if any.

Please advise.

Comment: I think you are over complicating by using re; I'm busy, will post answer in a while if no one else does :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more efficient way:

```
def journal_parser(context):
    with open("/tmp/journal_slice.log") as f:
        data = f.read()
        words = re.findall(r"|".join(keywords), data, re.I) # case insensitive matching by passing the re.I flag (ignore case)
        count = dict(Counter(words))
        print(count)
```

Comment: there is typo :) for word and words - tried edit - needs at least 6 chars :D

Comment: @Kasramvd : cool :) how can i use the same logic to return the matching line as well ?

Comment: @Ash_23 In that case, instead of reading the whole file at once you should read the file line by line and apply the regex on each line. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need those spaces around your keywords, depends on your data. But I think use of regex and extra libraries here is unnecessary imports.

```
keywords = ["error ", " boot ", " warning ", " traceback "]
src = '/tmp/journal_slice.log'
def journal_parser(s, kw):
    with open(s, 'r') as f:
        data = [w for line in f for w in line.split()]
        data = [x.lower() for x in data]
        print(data)
        for k in kw:
            print(f'{k} in src happens {data.count(k)} times')
journal_parser(src, keywords)
```

Note that f-string formatting in print does not work in early 3.x python
as well converting to lower might not be necessary - could just add all expected cases to keywords
and if the file is really huge you can yield line by line in a list and do list.count() on each line, just in that case you have to track your counts

Comment: list has count method, that you can and as I think should use :)